# Can't push Objects IDs to input value with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with `push()` function,
So I have a div in which you can pick images for gallery.

When user choose which images he wants, I'm getting images' ids and should push this ids inside input value.

**My HTML:**

```
<input class="custom-img-id" name="custom-img-id" type="hidden" value="" />
```

**My JS:**

```
frame.on( 'select', function() {
  var imgIdInput = $( '.custom-img-id' );
  // Get media attachment details from the frame state
  var attachment = frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

  var attachments = frame.state().get('selection').map(function( a ) {
    a.toJSON();
    return a;
  }),
  thesamepicture = false,
  i;

  for (i = 0; i < attachments.length; ++i) {
      imgContainer.append('<div data-id="' + attachments[i].id + '"><img src="' + attachments[i].attributes.url + '" alt="" style="max-width:100%;"/></div>');
      /* add an image ID to the array of all images */
      imgIdInput.val().split(",").push( attachments[i].id );
  }

});
```

I'm not posting all codes, but this part which reliable for it,
so I'm getting objects through mapping and call it `attachments`.

Then for each attachment will be created container for it.
And here is my problem, I can't push attachments' ids inside my input value. I'm not getting errors, just empty value.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this line of code

```
imgIdInput.val().split(",").push( attachments[i].id );
```

doesn't do what you seem to expect it will. `imgIdInput.val().split(",")` is an array, to which you then `push` a value - but since that array is not referenced anywhere else (you never assign it to a variable or otherwise do anything with it), this line of code in fact does absolutely nothing as far as observable effects in the rest of the program, or to the user, are concerned.

If you are trying to change the value inside the input, then you have to assign that back, using the jQuery `val` method again. I confess I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but the following hopefully gives you the idea even if I've not got it completely right:

```
  const imageIds = imgIdInput.val().split(",");
  for (let i = 0; i < attachments.length; ++i) {
      imgContainer.append('<div data-id="' + attachments[i].id + '"><img src="' + attachments[i].attributes.url + '" alt="" style="max-width:100%;"/></div>');
      /* add an image ID to the array of all images */
      imageIds.push( attachments[i].id );
  }
  imgIdInput.val(imageIds.join(","));
```

That is - you should first extract the array into a variable, `push` onto that in your loop (these `push`es now have an effect because they're changing an array which can be referenced in your script), then `join` those values in the array back together into a string which you set as your new input value.

I will note in concluding that you probably don't want the overhead (minimal though it likely is) of using `split` and `join` to go back and forth between arrays and strings. You can simply work with a string and do something like

```
imageIdString += `,${attachments[i].id}`
```

inside the loop, so that you're simply adding to a string.